# Alfresco AuthenticationService.getCurrentUserName() always returns admin?

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to get user name for logged in user in alfresco using

```
String name = serviceRegistry.getAuthenticationService().getCurrentUser();
```

But it always return admin regardless of which user is logged in.

Then i tried

```
String name = AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser();
```

It also returns admin for all users.

I googled it without any success. Is it a bug in alfresco or do i need to take care of something else also to get appropriate user name?

Or is there any other way to get currently logged user name?

Comment: Where is this code running? And are you sure you really haven't logged in as admin when calling it?

Comment: Are you using runAs('admin') ?

Comment: I got it now.I am calling this code in a webscript. Whenever i try to invoke this webscript, it asks for a popup. If i put admin credentials in it, it always takes admin as current user name. I am trying with /wcs authentication now but this redirects to explorer login. Any way suggested.

Comment: well, if you run the webscript with as admin then it should give you admin as fully authenticated user. Execute the webscript with another user & you'll get another fully authenticated user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String name = AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser();
```

is the correct way to get the userName of your current user.

Every webscript has an descriptor where you can configure the authentication that is required to execute the webscript: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/api-wsdl-authentication.html

Typically, you will use `<authentication>user</authentication>`

There are two different ['runtimes'](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Script_Runtimes) in the alfresco repo that can be used to execute a webscript:

1. /alfresco/s/... (long version /alfresco/service) that uses HTTP Basic Authentication
2. /alfresco/wcs/... (long version /alfresco/wcservice) that uses Alfresco's WebClient (Alfresco Explorer) authentication.